# Change horizontal scroll to vertical scroll

Tags: css, scrollbar, haml

I've haml code that is having a horizontal scrolling. How can I change this to a vertical scroll?

I tried this:

```
.content_comments
{
    height: 90px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:thin;
}
```

The horizontal scrolling is now hidden, But the end of the line is not visible...

And I want that the 'overflow-x' will change to 'overflow-y' and move to the next line.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Put the HTML also. It will be easy to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try word-wrap

```
.content_comments
    {
     word-wrap: break-word;
        height: 90px;
        width: 500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width:thin;
    }
```